# Bootstrap data api way vs javascript way

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I see the usage of bootstrap using data attribute api as well as javascript. I want to know whether I can avoid javascript way of using if I am comfortable with data attribute api. Because I am able to build a whole site by just using classes and data attributes. Please let me know when there are mandatory situations to use javascript way of using bootstrap. Thanks

[Edit]:

After adding bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css, can we just stick to data attribute api way of bootstrap usage (i.e. just using classes and data attributes without writing our own javascript)? Or are there any situations where we need to write javascript explicitly

Comment: Some parts of bootstrap require the use of javascript, even you do not need to write your own javascript to use them.  So its not clear what it is you are referring to.

Comment: My doubt is I am able to create a webpage using only classes and data attributes. However, I could see so much javascript stuff in bootstrap official site. As I am able to use data api to fulfill my all requirements, can I leave javascript stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you need to use bootstrap tooltips you have to initialize the `$().tooltip()` function of bootstrap in your javascript code. Else tooltips wont work. Rest of the javascript implementation of bootstrap are for binding events and calling methods which may not be required for your application and are not mandatory